# Forcing non-temporary in RAII by compile Error C++

Tags: c++, raii, most-vexing-parse

When one uses lock_guard in C++ like this:

```
 lock_guard<mutex>(lock);
```

The compiler complains:

```
no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::lock_guard<std::mutex>'
```

Because the correct use is:

```
 lock_guard<mutex> guard(lock);
```

I would like to write a custom RAII allocator that also coplains when this happens - I tried disabling copy consturctor and assigment operator, but so far nothing works.

Comment: That's small letter L. Also irrelevant...

Comment: damn it! not the first time I've done this on a question.

Comment: There's no current way to do this.

Comment: Whenever your statement begins with `Type (anything)` , be on guard

Comment: The main question has been somewhat obscured by the MVP issue ... if your main thrust was to ask "How do I design an object so that it cannot be created as a temporary" then the answer is, as TC says, "You can't";  (and `lock_guard` does not have this property either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to achieve your goal, but I guess I know what's happened to `lock_guard<mutex>(lock)`.

Let's do some experiment.

**Experiment 1**

```
int(x);
x = 1;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

The experiment reveals we have declared a variable `x`, even though there is a pair of brackets.

**Experiment 2**

```
class Widget
{
};

class WidgetGuard
{
private:
    Widget& widget;
public:
    WidgetGuard(Widget& w)
        : widget(w)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Widget w1;

    WidgetGuard wg1(w1);
    WidgetGuard(w1);     //Error!
    WidgetGuard{ w1 };   //Pass!
}
```

We define a `Widget` class and `WidgetGuard` class to emulate `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard`. When we try to declare a temporary `WidgetGuard` with brackets, it gives an error. But doing so with braces compiles.

This can be explained with Experiment 1. The compiler parses `WidgetGuard{ w1 }` to be "create temporary". But it parses `WidgetGuard(w1)` to be "declare variable `w1`"! There are two sources of error: reusing the same name, and no default constructor in `WidgetGuard`.

**Experiment 0**

Returning to `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard`, let's try braces...

```
std::mutex m;
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> {m};
```

... and it works.

A temporary of `std::lock_guard` can be created. We just can.

Comment: §6.8 [stmt.ambig] is the relevant subclause in the standard.